# Cancellation across the Flowables when implementing branching logic

Tags: java, rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-java3

I have some `Flowable`s composed using `FlowableTransformer` like this:

```
public static FlowableTransformer<I, O> transformer() {
    return f -> {
        return Flowable.mergeArray(5, 5, f.filter(...).map(...), f.filter(...).map(...));
    }
}
```

**The basic use case here is have some form of branching logic** - if the elements are A (`filter`) then do B (`map`) or if they are C then do D.

However, downstream, when I store the `Disposable` and later call `cancel` on it, cancellation only bubbles up the stream as far as the `Flowable` returned by `mergeArray`. Upstream of that, i.e. the operators upstream of the call to `compose(transformer())`, cancellation is never received.

So I thought this was a problem with `Flowable.merge()` itself (or rather: my lack of understanding), so I changed to using a `replay()` and a `ConnectableFlowable`:

```
public static FlowableTransformer<I, O> transformer() {
    return f -> {
        ConnectableFlowable<TaggedUpdates> cf = taggedUpdateFlowables.replay(5);
        
        Flowable<O> o = f
            .filter(...)
            .map(...)
            .concatWith(
                    cf
                        .filter(...)
                        .map(...)
            );
        
        cf.connect();
        return o;
    };
}
```

However - the same thing happens. `cancellation` only bubbles up as far as the `ConnectableFlowable`.

However, I need to propogate cancellation up the full Flowable so that the source of items stops producing.

Is there a way of doing that? Or should I go about the branching logic in a different way?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I'm currently working around it. Instead of using a merge or `replay` I've changed it to just use `flatMap`:

```
public static FlowableTransformer<I, O> transformer() {
    return f -> {
        return f
            .flatMap(i -> {
                return Flowable.just(i.items)
                     .filter(...)
                     .map(...)
                     .concatWith(
                         .flatMap(i -> {
                             Flowable.just(i.items)
                                 .filter(...)
                                 .map(...)
                         })
                     );
               });
    };
}
```

However, I'm a bit worried later I'll not be able to do this workaround where I *do* need to use `replay`, e.g. where computation of the upstream is expensive.